# List not recognising for Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to run a simple bar chart on plotly with a one dimensional list taken  from Excel. The file prints ok (myList  = ['45,21,45,54,87,34,52,78,9,79']) and I'm assuming that I split it into a list of strings. I want to now change them into int so that Plotly can recognise to chart as its only plotting as one big bar now (I'm guessing the string all together?)

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go 

    file = open("myFile.csv", "r") *




    myData= file.read() 
    myList = myData.split("\n") 
    print(myList) 

    newList = []

    for element in myList:
        newList.append(int(element))

    print(newList)

    y = newList


    fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(y=y)])
    fig.update_layout(title_text='This is my bar chart displaying my figures')
    fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Why do you put this in brackets? `y = (myList)`
B) Isn't it because here: `fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(y=y)])` you use your old list with strings instead of using `newlist`?

This solves your error:

```
mylist = "".join(mylist)
mylist = mylist.split(",")
```

It can be done in 1 line.

Comment: Are you trying to answer the question? Or are you asking clarification questions? In the latter case please understand https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead (Downvote not by me though.)

Comment: Sorry that was just a mistake on my part there, changed that around but the error still remains:  newList.append(int(element))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '45,21,45,54,87,34,52,78,9,79'

Comment: @Yunnosch That "New contributor" != inexperienced ;)

Comment: @peter123 True, many users do not have that "New contributor" anymore, but still fail to use StackOverflow as it is meant to be used. Maybe this helps you for future posts https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @peter123 Yes, I feel with you. It is usually much more helpful to comment and point out shortcomings to an author than to downvote or close-vote one of the (often ill-fitting) standard reasons without explanation. That way newbies have a much better chance at improving. Even a link to a relevant rule (though helpful information) should better be accomanied by a short explanation, to point out how it applies to the post in question.